# Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to prove that $f(z)=\cos(z)$ is an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Now I know that $\cos(z)=\cos(x+iy)$ but I don't know how to do the partial derivatives

Comment: Try splitting $\cos(x+iy)$ into real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1):

I would write cosine in its complex form:
$$
\cos(x+iy) = \frac{e^{i(x + iy)} + e^{-i(x+iy)}}{2}.
$$
Then you can expand the right hand side to write 
$$
\cos(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)
$$
for some functions $u,v : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.  Then check that the Cauch-Riemann equations hold.